# Distinct values from Array inside Array of objects

Tags: javascript

Ive got an array of objects. Inside each object there is another array.
I want to extract distinct values from these arrays.

```js
var data = [
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['A', 'B']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'Two', designs: ['C']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['D']},
            {categorie: 'Other', type: 'Three', designs: ['C', 'D']}
        ];
console.log([...new Set(data.map(x => x.categorie))]);
console.log([...new Set(data.map(x => x.type))]);

//expected output for designs ['A','B','C','D']
```

Comment: like `console.log([...new Set(data.flatMap(x => x.designs))]);`?

Comment: _"expected output for designs"_ - Why are you then returning `x.categorie`/`x.type`?

Comment: both other console.logs are just an example how i would return distincts from categorie and type. But dont know how to do it from designs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`

```js
var data = [
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['A', 'B']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'Two', designs: ['C']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['D']},
            {categorie: 'Other', type: 'Three', designs: ['C', 'D']}
        ];

console.log([...new Set(data.flatMap(x => x.designs))]);

//expected output for designs ['A','B','C','D']
```

If your browser doesn't support `flatMap()` then you can use `concat()` with spread operator.

```js
var data = [
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['A', 'B']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'Two', designs: ['C']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['D']},
            {categorie: 'Other', type: 'Three', designs: ['C', 'D']}
        ];

console.log([...new Set([].concat(...data.map(x => x.designs)))]);

//expected output for designs ['A','B','C','D']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a set from the designs as well.

```js
var data = [{ categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['A', 'B'] }, { categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'Two', designs: ['C'] }, { categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['D'] }, { categorie: 'Other', type: 'Three', designs: ['C', 'D'] }],
    unique = data.reduce((s, { designs }) => [...new Set([...s, ...designs])], []);

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: What about `let res = [...new Set(data.reduce((a,{designs}) => [...a,...designs],[]))]`. Wouldn't it be better to just flatten first and form a set once at the end, instead of forming a set on every reduction step?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is this:

```js
var data = [
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['A', 'B']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'Two', designs: ['C']},
            {categorie: 'Stuff', type: 'One', designs: ['D']},
            {categorie: 'Other', type: 'Three', designs: ['C', 'D']}
        ];

var uniqueLetters = []

data.forEach(obj => {
  obj.designs.forEach(letter => {
    if (uniqueLetters.indexOf(letter) < 0) {
      uniqueLetters.push(letter)
    }
  })
})

console.log(uniqueLetters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Plain JavaScript solution.

```
var output = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
for(var j=0; j<data[i].designs.length; j++ ){
  if(output.indexOf(data[i].designs[j]) === -1) {
  output.push(data[i].designs[j])
  }
}
}
console.log(output)
//expected output for designs ['A','B','C','D']
```